# Can I construct a Twitter tweet URL that makes sure I'm in the right screen name?

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

I can construct a URL that will post a Tweet (but ask for confirmation) with pre-written text:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=My%20awesome%20message.

If I am not logged in, the web page this generates include a username/password form.

However I have 2 Twitter accounts (one for work, one for personal use).  I want the URL to specify that the message is to go out via my work account.

Is there a field I can add that will require the message to be posted by a particular screen name?   i.e. either by giving an error if I'm not logged into that account or ask for the password of the desired screen name and switch to the account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible. The only options available are those listed at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents

- url
- via
- text
- in_reply_to
- hashtags
- related